# Nginx 'and' condition to compare IPs

Tags: nginx

I have a condition of the form:

```
location ~ / {
    if ($http_x_forwarded_for != 10.10.0.100) {
      return 404;
    }
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

I want to add more IPs to the list such that if the request is received from an IP other than `A` and `B` I return 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `geo` map to set a variable that defines condition when 404 needs to be returned:

```
geo $http_x_forwarded_for $return_404 {
    default 0;
    10.10.0.100 1;
    10.10.0.101 1;
}

server {
    server_name example.com;
    if ($return_404 = 1) {
        return 404;
    }
    location ~ / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex `location` match doen't needed for this particular case. Use [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) directive:

```
map $http_x_forwarded_for $denied {
    10.10.0.100    1;
    10.10.0.101    1;
    ...
}

server {
    ...
    location / {
        if ($denied) {
            return 404;
        }
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    ...
```

You can deny the full IP subnets this way using regex matching, for example, deny all IPs from 10.10.0.0/24 subnet:

```
map $http_x_forwarded_for $denied {
    ~^10\.10\.0\.     1;
    ...
}
```

Note that the `map` directive should be declared **outside** the `server` block.